# Azure: Map public IP to a specific port on VM

Tags: azure

I have several sites set up on an Azure VM in IIS, each with different ports.  I need to link these to specific domain names on my DNS.  I'm aware that you can't specify ports in DNS settings, so my best understanding is that I need to create Public IP Addresses in Azure and then link these to IP Configurations on the Network Interface.

I've been using the following tutorial:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-portal

However, I see no mention of ports in the tutorial.  How can I achieve what I'm trying to do, or have I misunderstood how you host multiple websites on IIS?

Comment: What's the reason for doing it on different ports and not using host headers?

Comment: Because none of us on the team knew about host headers. I am now enlightened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you looked at using Host Headers in IIS? this should allow you to use a single IP address and port combination to represent multiple sites in IIS:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx

If you can use host headers then you wont need to use multiple Azure public IPs.